# Export to Mapbox (TileMill) from PSD (or SVG/PNG)

Tags: postgis, tiles, tilemill, svg, png

Newbie question: I designed a map (not Earth-related) in Photoshop and I want to use something like Mapbox to serve the map and make it dynamic (bounding boxes, zoom in/out, etc). How can I go from an SVG/PNG to a tile-based map?

TileMill accepts as data input geoJSON, SQLite, PostGIS. For example:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"BRA","properties":{"name":"Brazil"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-57.625133,-30.216295],[-56.2909,-28.852761],[-55.162286,-27.881915],[-54.490725,-27.474757],[-53.648735,-26.923473],[-53.628349,-26.124865],[-54.13005,-25.547639],[-54.625291,-25.739255],[-54.428946,-25.162185],[-54.293476,-24.5708],[-54.29296,-24.021014],[-54.652834,-23.839578],[-55.027902,-24.001274],[-55.400747,-23.956935],[-55.517639,-23.571998],[-55.610683,-22.655619],[-55.797958,-22.35693],[-56.473317,-22.0863],[-56.88151,-22.282154],[-57.937156,-22.090176],[-57.870674,-20.732688],[-58.166392,-20.176701],[-57.853802,-19.969995],[-57.949997,-19.400004],[-57.676009,-18.96184],[-57.498371,-18.174188],[-57.734558,-17.552468],[-58.280804,-17.27171],[-58.388058,-16.877109],[-58.24122,-16.299573],[-60.15839,-16.258284],[-60.542966,-15.09391],[-60.251149,-15.077219],[-60.264326,-14.645979],[-60.459198,-14.354007],[-60.503304,-13.775955],[-61.084121,-13.479384],[-61.713204,-13.489202],[-62.127081,-13.198781],[-62.80306,-13.000653],[-63.196499,-12.627033],[-64.316353,-12.461978],[-65.402281,-11.56627],[-65.321899,-10.895872],[-65.444837,-10.511451],[-65.338435,-9.761988],[-66.646908,-9.931331],[-67.173801,-10.306812],[-68.048192,-10.712059],[-68.271254,-11.014521],[-68.786158,-11.03638],[-69.529678,-10.951734],[-70.093752,-11.123972],[-70.548686,-11.009147],[-70.481894,-9.490118],[-71.302412,-10.079436],[-72.184891,-10.053598],[-72.563033,-9.520194],[-73.226713,-9.462213],[-73.015383,-9.032833],[-73.571059,-8.424447],[-73.987235,-7.52383],[-73.723401,-7.340999],[-73.724487,-6.918595],[-73.120027,-6.629931],[-73.219711,-6.089189],[-72.964507,-5.741251],[-72.891928,-5.274561],[-71.748406,-4.593983],[-70.928843,-4.401591],[-70.794769,-4.251265],[-69.893635,-4.298187],[-69.444102,-1.556287],[-69.420486,-1.122619],[-69.577065,-0.549992],[-70.020656,-0.185156],[-70.015566,0.541414],[-69.452396,0.706159],[-69.252434,0.602651],[-69.218638,0.985677],[-69.804597,1.089081],[-69.816973,1.714805],[-67.868565,1.692455],[-67.53781,2.037163],[-67.259998,1.719999],[-67.065048,1.130112],[-66.876326,1.253361],[-66.325765,0.724452],[-65.548267,0.789254],[-65.354713,1.095282],[-64.611012,1.328731],[-64.199306,1.492855],[-64.083085,1.916369],[-63.368788,2.2009],[-63.422867,2.411068],[-64.269999,2.497006],[-64.408828,3.126786],[-64.368494,3.79721],[-64.816064,4.056445],[-64.628659,4.148481],[-63.888343,4.02053],[-63.093198,3.770571],[-62.804533,4.006965],[-62.08543,4.162124],[-60.966893,4.536468],[-60.601179,4.918098],[-60.733574,5.200277],[-60.213683,5.244486],[-59.980959,5.014061],[-60.111002,4.574967],[-59.767406,4.423503],[-59.53804,3.958803],[-59.815413,3.606499],[-59.974525,2.755233],[-59.718546,2.24963],[-59.646044,1.786894],[-59.030862,1.317698],[-58.540013,1.268088],[-58.429477,1.463942],[-58.11345,1.507195],[-57.660971,1.682585],[-57.335823,1.948538],[-56.782704,1.863711],[-56.539386,1.899523],[-55.995698,1.817667],[-55.9056,2.021996],[-56.073342,2.220795],[-55.973322,2.510364],[-55.569755,2.421506],[-55.097587,2.523748],[-54.524754,2.311849],[-54.088063,2.105557],[-53.778521,2.376703],[-53.554839,2.334897],[-53.418465,2.053389],[-52.939657,2.124858],[-52.556425,2.504705],[-52.249338,3.241094],[-51.657797,4.156232],[-51.317146,4.203491],[-51.069771,3.650398],[-50.508875,1.901564],[-49.974076,1.736483],[-49.947101,1.04619],[-50.699251,0.222984],[-50.388211,-0.078445],[-48.620567,-0.235489],[-48.584497,-1.237805],[-47.824956,-0.581618],[-46.566584,-0.941028],[-44.905703,-1.55174],[-44.417619,-2.13775],[-44.581589,-2.691308],[-43.418791,-2.38311],[-41.472657,-2.912018],[-39.978665,-2.873054],[-38.500383,-3.700652],[-37.223252,-4.820946],[-36.452937,-5.109404],[-35.597796,-5.149504],[-35.235389,-5.464937],[-34.89603,-6.738193],[-34.729993,-7.343221],[-35.128212,-8.996401],[-35.636967,-9.649282],[-37.046519,-11.040721],[-37.683612,-12.171195],[-38.423877,-13.038119],[-38.673887,-13.057652],[-38.953276,-13.79337],[-38.882298,-15.667054],[-39.161092,-17.208407],[-39.267339,-17.867746],[-39.583521,-18.262296],[-39.760823,-19.599113],[-40.774741,-20.904512],[-40.944756,-21.937317],[-41.754164,-22.370676],[-41.988284,-22.97007],[-43.074704,-22.967693],[-44.647812,-23.351959],[-45.352136,-23.796842],[-46.472093,-24.088969],[-47.648972,-24.885199],[-48.495458,-25.877025],[-48.641005,-26.623698],[-48.474736,-27.175912],[-48.66152,-28.186135],[-48.888457,-28.674115],[-49.587329,-29.224469],[-50.696874,-30.984465],[-51.576226,-31.777698],[-52.256081,-32.24537],[-52.7121,-33.196578],[-53.373662,-33.768378],[-53.650544,-33.202004],[-53.209589,-32.727666],[-53.787952,-32.047243],[-54.572452,-31.494511],[-55.60151,-30.853879],[-55.973245,-30.883076],[-56.976026,-30.109686],[-57.625133,-30.216295]]]}}
]}
```

However, I don’t have those coordinates to define the polygon area. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't quite how Tilemill is intended to be used. You would need to convert your svg to geojson and add attributes, then redo all your styling.

EDIT: You can [use rasters in Tilemill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/) if you save to tif. Projection might be tricky but for a fictitious place it might work ok.

Since you already have an image, something like [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org/) to just cut your image into tiles and generate tiles for all scales you want is probably a better choice. If you still want it served by mapbox you'll need to then convert that tile set into the [mbtiles](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/mbtiles/) format.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll give that a go. Maybe I will go with MapTiler, as it might be the best solution.

Comment: Maptiler will work directly with Openlayers/Leaflet too. Also if you do the tilemill way, just stretch your image to spherical mercator pixel extent and projection won't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using PNG you can also use leaflet, just follow the workflow in this blog post:
http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/06/showing-zoomify-images-with-leaflet.html

Hosting something like this on mapbox seems a bit pointless if you don't real world data or really big imagery, you can just host it on any webserver, its just basic html/javascript.